# getting a localized "global" scope for a v8 function

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I am wanting to set up a sort of localized scope that will act like a set of globals inside of a particular function, but I want to inherit all the globals that may already exist.

There has to be an easier way to do this than what I'm doing, however.

What I do right now is I convert the scope object that I am wanting to use into a string that consists of var declarations and assignments, in javascript.   I put this inside of an anonymous function that returns my original function code, and invoke the anonymous funcion to give me the inner function.

The MAKESTRING macro uses a stringstream to define a string

```
std::prefix_code = convert_object_to_vars(scope);
std::code = MAKESTRING("(function() { " << prefix_code << "return (" << fdefinition << "); })()");
v8::TryCatch try_catch;
v8::Handle<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(_isolate, code.c_str()));
if (try_catch.HasCaught())
    return v8::Undefined(_isolate);
if (script.IsEmpty())
    return v8::Undefined(_isolate);
v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run();
if (try_catch.HasCaught())
    return v8::Undefined(_isolate);
if (!result->IsFunction())
    return v8::Undefined(_isolate);
return result
```

The scope variable is simply an v8::Object, consisting of key value pairs, describing the assorted variables that exist in the scope and their initial values.

The convert_object_to_vars function is where things get dicey... although this is seeming to work, I must explicitly write code in the convert function to handle each new type that I am wanting to supported, and as I add more custom types, this function is growing rapidly in complexity, so I am not convinced that this is a long term solution.   Additionally much of the code on convert_object_to_vars must also be replicated in another function which returns a human-readable representation of such an object.

There has to be an easier way.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to re-invent `with`.

Comment: That would not be a bad way to describe it.

Comment: Did he answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently while developing my thread-pool native add-on.

The key to getting this to work is configure the context that the function will execute in with the globals you want accessible within the function.

This needs to happen before you compile and run the stringified function.  I've given a small sample below.  `myGlobalProperty` will be available as a global within the function because it was compiled and run within the currently entered context.

```
// configure context before executing function
HandleScope scope;
Handle<Object> contextObject = Context::GetCurrent()->Global();
contextObject->Set(String::NewSymbol("myGlobalProperty"), Object::New());

// turn function into string
String::Utf8Value funcStr(functionToExecute->ToString());
string funcToExe(*funcStr);
funcToExe.insert(0, "(");
funcToExe.append(")()");

// compile and run the function
// this will execute within the currently entered and configured context
Handle<Script> functionScript = Script::New(String::New(funcToExe.c_str()));
functionScript->Run();
```

If you want to access the global variables after executing the function.  You will need to access them via the context as seen below:

```
Handle<Value> myGlobal = contextObject->Get(String::NewSymbol("myGlobalProperty"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers my question.  If I understand correctly, this just creates a new Object that is accessible via contextObject.  I need the members of my object to be accessible within the javascript code as if they were global.  As someone pointed out above, it is very similar in concept to making a `with` statement, but there doesn't appear to be a way to specify that a script run inside of a "`with`-like" context.